# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: jquery, javascript, server

I finally got my javascript references with no 404.  The first info I fill out into the html form gives me console errors.

Here is my JavaScript that is causing me an issue:

```
/* global define, module, require */
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['crypto-js', 'ws'], factory);
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
        // Node. Export.
        module.exports = factory(require('crypto-js'), require('ws'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals (root is window)
        root.GameSparks = factory(root.CryptoJS, root.WebSocket || root.MozWebSocket);
    }
}(this, function(CryptoJS, WebSocket) {

var GameSparks = function() {};

GameSparks.prototype = {

    init: function(options) {
        this.options = options;
        this.socketUrl = options.url;

        this.pendingRequests = {};
        this.requestCounter = 0;

        this.connect();
    },

    buildServiceUrl: function(live, options) {
        var stage;
        var urlAddition = options.key;
        var credential;
        var index;

        if (live) {
          stage = "live";
        } else {
          stage = "preview";
        }

        if (!options.credential || options.credential.length === 0) {
          credential = "device";
        } else {
          credential = options.credential;
        }

        index = options.secret.indexOf(":");
        if (index > 0) {
            credential = "secure";

            urlAddition = options.secret.substr(0, index) + "/" + urlAddition;
        }

        return "wss://" + stage + "-" + urlAddition + ".ws.gamesparks.net/ws/" + credential + "/" + urlAddition;
    },

    initPreview: function(options) {
        options.url = this.buildServiceUrl(false, options);
        this.init(options);
    },

    initLive: function(options) {
        options.url = this.buildServiceUrl(true, options);
        this.init(options);
    },

    reset: function() {
        this.initialised = false;
        this.connected = false;
        this.error = false;
        this.disconnected = false;

        if (this.webSocket != null){
            this.webSocket.onclose = null;
            this.webSocket.close();
        }
    },

    connect: function() {
        this.reset();

        try {
            this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.socketUrl);
            this.webSocket.onopen = this.onWebSocketOpen.bind(this);
            this.webSocket.onclose = this.onWebSocketClose.bind(this);
            this.webSocket.onerror = this.onWebSocketError.bind(this);
            this.webSocket.onmessage = this.onWebSocketMessage.bind(this);
        } catch(e) {
            this.log(e.message);
        }
    },

    disconnect: function() {
        if (this.webSocket && this.connected) {
            this.disconnected = true;
            this.webSocket.close();
        }
    },

    onWebSocketOpen: function(ev) {
        this.log('WebSocket onOpen');

        if (this.options.onOpen) {
            this.options.onOpen(ev);
        }

        this.connected = true;
    },

    onWebSocketClose: function(ev) {
        this.log('WebSocket onClose');

        if (this.options.onClose) {
            this.options.onClose(ev);
        }

        this.connected = false;

        // Attemp a re-connection if not in error state or deliberately disconnected.
        if (!this.error && !this.disconnected) {
            this.connect();
        }
    },

    onWebSocketError: function(ev) {

        this.log('WebSocket onError: Sorry, but there is some problem with your socket or the server is down');

        if (this.options.onError) {
            this.options.onError(ev);
        }

        // Reset the socketUrl to the original.
        this.socketUrl = this.options.url;

        this.error = true;
    },

    onWebSocketMessage: function(message) {
        this.log('WebSocket onMessage: ' + message.data);

        var result;
        try {
            result = JSON.parse(message.data);
        } catch (e) {
            this.log('An error ocurred while parsing the JSON Data: ' + message + '; Error: ' + e);
            return;
        }

        if (this.options.onMessage) {
            this.options.onMessage(result);
        }

        // Extract any auth token.
        if (result['authToken']) {
            this.authToken = result['authToken'];
            delete result['authToken'];
        }

        if (result['connectUrl']) {
            // Any time a connectUrl is in the response we should update and reconnect.
            this.socketUrl = result['connectUrl'];
            this.connect();
        }

        var resultType = result['@class'];

        if (resultType === '.AuthenticatedConnectResponse') {
            this.handshake(result);
        } else if (resultType.match(/Response$/)){
            if (result['requestId']) {
                var requestId = result['requestId'];
                delete result['requestId'];

                if (this.pendingRequests[requestId]) {
                    this.pendingRequests[requestId](result);
                    this.pendingRequests[requestId] = null;
                }
            }
        }

    },

    handshake: function(result) {

        if (result['nonce']) {

            var hmac;

            if (this.options.onNonce) {
                hmac = this.options.onNonce(result['nonce']);
            } else {
                hmac = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(result['nonce'], this.options.secret));
            }

            var toSend = {
                '@class' : '.AuthenticatedConnectRequest',
                hmac : hmac
            };

            if (this.authToken) {
                toSend.authToken = this.authToken;
            }

            if (this.sessionId) {
                toSend.sessionId = this.sessionId;
            }

            const browserData = this.getBrowserData();
            toSend.platform = browserData.browser;
            toSend.os = browserData.operatingSystem;

            this.webSocketSend(toSend);

        } else if (result['sessionId']) {
            this.sessionId = result['sessionId'];
            this.initialised = true;

            if (this.options.onInit) {
                this.options.onInit();
            }

            this.keepAliveInterval = window.setInterval(this.keepAlive.bind(this), 30000);
        }
    },

    keepAlive: function() {
        if (this.initialised && this.connected) {
            this.webSocket.send(' ');
        }
    },

    send: function(requestType, onResponse){
        this.sendWithData(requestType, {}, onResponse);
    },

    sendWithData: function(requestType, json, onResponse) {
        if (!this.initialised) {
            onResponse({ error: 'NOT_INITIALISED' });
            return;
        }

        // Ensure requestType starts with a dot.
        if (requestType.indexOf('.') !== 0) {
            requestType = '.' + requestType;
        }

        json['@class'] = requestType;

        json.requestId = (new Date()).getTime() + "_" + (++this.requestCounter);

        if (onResponse != null) {
            this.pendingRequests[json.requestId] = onResponse;
            // Time out handler.
            setTimeout((function() {
                if (this.pendingRequests[json.requestId]) {
                    this.pendingRequests[json.requestId]({ error: 'NO_RESPONSE' });
                }
            }).bind(this), 32000);
        }

        this.webSocketSend(json);
    },

    webSocketSend: function(data) {

        if (this.options.onSend) {
            this.options.onSend(data);
        }

        var requestString = JSON.stringify(data);
        this.log('WebSocket send: ' + requestString);
        this.webSocket.send(requestString);
    },

    getSocketUrl: function() {
        return this.socketUrl;
    },

    getSessionId: function() {
        return this.sessionId;
    },

    getAuthToken: function() {
        return this.authToken;
    },

    setAuthToken: function(authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
    },

    isConnected: function() {
        return this.connected;
    },

    log: function(message) {
        if (this.options.logger) {
            this.options.logger(message);
        }
    },

    getBrowserData: function() {

        var browsers = [
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'Chrome',
                identity: 'Chrome'
            },
            {   string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'OmniWeb',
                versionSearch: 'OmniWeb/',
                identity: 'OmniWeb'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: 'Apple',
                identity: 'Safari',
                versionSearch: 'Version'
            },
            {
                prop: window.opera,
                identity: 'Opera',
                versionSearch: 'Version'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: 'iCab',
                identity: 'iCab'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: 'KDE',
                identity: 'Konqueror'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'Firefox',
                identity: 'Firefox'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.vendor,
                subString: 'Camino',
                identity: 'Camino'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'Netscape',
                identity: 'Netscape'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'MSIE',
                identity: 'Explorer',
                versionSearch: 'MSIE'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'Gecko',
                identity: 'Mozilla',
                versionSearch: 'rv'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.userAgent,
                subString: 'Mozilla',
                identity: 'Netscape',
                versionSearch: 'Mozilla'
            }
        ];

        var operatingSystems = [
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: 'Win',
                identity: 'Windows'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: 'Mac',
                identity: 'Mac'
            },
            {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: 'iPhone',
               identity: 'iPhone/iPod'
            },
            {
                string: navigator.platform,
                subString: 'Linux',
                identity: 'Linux'
            }
        ];

        function searchForIdentity(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var string = data[i].string;
                var prop = data[i].prop;

                if (string) {
                    // Look for the sub string in the string.
                    if (string.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                        return data[i].identity;
                    }
                } else if (prop) {
                    return data[i].identity;
                }
            }
        }

        return {
            browser: searchForIdentity(browsers),
            operatingSystem: searchForIdentity(operatingSystems)
        };
    }
};

return GameSparks;

}));
```

As you probably saw, the line that is giving me issue is:

```
index = options.secret.indexOf(":");
            if (index > 0) {
                credential = "secure";
```

I have no idea what the issue is.  It is a backend server, and I know they suggested I use a third party server to encrypt my API key...

Comment: This seems more specific to GameSparks than to javascript in general. Whoever is passing the options variable to initLive or initPreview is not setting options.secret to anything.

Comment: I'm harassing the guys at GameSparks to get specifics on this too.  So far, silence.  So it is left up to me to find a way!  Thanks Tommy O for the edits.

Comment: I heard back from the GameSparks guys.  They asked if I modified the html in any way, which I didn't.  Except for the references to where I keep the java.  I was getting 404 errors before, until I fixed that.  Their answer was, essentially, "it should be working."  That is why I come to the real pros.

Comment: I should mention you guys can go to www.martialparks.com and check this stuff out for yourself.

Comment: I replaced  this: initPreview: function(options) {
   options.url = this.buildServiceUrl(false, options);
   this.init(options);
  },                                                                                            
 with this:  initPreview: function(options) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(options));
 options.url = this.buildServiceUrl(false, options);
 this.init(options);
}                              With the intention that when I attempt this, i'll get a log of what is actually happening.  No idea how to access that log...but I'll figure it out.

Comment: The default console.log goes to the browser console.(Press F12 on Chrome or IE). If you haven't found F12 yet, welcome to the world of browser debugging. You can set breakpoints right on the line where you get the options back and then hover over variables to see what they contain, no console logging necessary

Comment: I attempted to attach the code into the js file in my template, and refresh the page.  It reverts back to the old version.  With either code, I get this in the console:  VM263 gamesparks.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at GameSparks.buildServiceUrl (VM263 gamesparks.js:47)
    at GameSparks.initPreview (VM263 gamesparks.js:58)
    at init ((index):28)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):14)
buildServiceUrl @ VM263 gamesparks.js:47
initPreview @ VM263 gamesparks.js:58
init @ (index):28
onclick @ (index):14

Comment: Thanks SpectacularBob.  I've been using the browser console since I started this mess (how I found my 404 errors).  I sent the console log to the devs at Gamesparks (and now here.)  I am learning, very quickly.  But without a complete conceptual understanding of how this script works, it is impossible to troubleshoot on my own.   Not without suspending the project for four years while I study javascript.  No time for that.  I have to learn through trial and error...total immersion!

Answer (score 0):

I revisited the SDK, and it looks like the devs had issued an update.  I was, strangely using the updated javascript, but not the updated html file the references the new js.  With the API key and secret, I can handshake perfectly now.

No begins the long battle of customizing the UI and content!